# Prometheus node_exporter Metrics file discovered

Tags: hardware

I found a 'Metrics' file during a test containing:

```
# HELP go_gc_duration_seconds A summary of the GC invocation durations.
# TYPE go_gc_duration_seconds summary
go_gc_duration_seconds{quantile="0"} 0.000115592
go_gc_duration_seconds{quantile="0.25"} 0.00030955
go_gc_duration_seconds{quantile="0.5"} 0.000495939
go_gc_duration_seconds{quantile="0.75"} 0.001984573
go_gc_duration_seconds{quantile="1"} 0.012666198
go_gc_duration_seconds_sum 1239.090613534
go_gc_duration_seconds_count 598634
# HELP go_goroutines Number of goroutines that currently exist.
# TYPE go_goroutines gauge
go_goroutines 17
# HELP go_info Information about the Go environment.
# TYPE go_info gauge
go_info{version="go1.11.2"} 1
# HELP go_memstats_alloc_bytes Number of bytes allocated and still in use.
# TYPE go_memstats_alloc_bytes gauge
go_memstats_alloc_bytes 3.09436e+06
# HELP go_memstats_alloc_bytes_total Total number of bytes allocated, even if freed.
# TYPE go_memstats_alloc_bytes_total counter
go_memstats_alloc_bytes_total 1.444187504656e+12
# HELP go_memstats_buck_hash_sys_bytes Number of bytes used by the profiling bucket hash table.
# TYPE go_memstats_buck_hash_sys_bytes gauge
go_memstats_buck_hash_sys_bytes 2.75478e+06
# HELP go_memstats_frees_total Total number of frees.
# TYPE go_memstats_frees_total counter
go_memstats_frees_total 1.9690278389e+10
# HELP go_memstats_gc_cpu_fraction The fraction of this program's available CPU time used by the GC since the program started.
# TYPE go_memstats_gc_cpu_fraction gauge
go_memstats_gc_cpu_fraction 0.010579384265189175
# HELP go_memstats_gc_sys_bytes Number of bytes used for garbage collection system metadata.
# TYPE go_memstats_gc_sys_bytes gauge
go_memstats_gc_sys_bytes 2.387968e+06
# HELP go_memstats_heap_alloc_bytes Number of heap bytes allocated and still in use.
# TYPE go_memstats_heap_alloc_bytes gauge
go_memstats_heap_alloc_bytes 3.09436e+06
# HELP go_memstats_heap_idle_bytes Number of heap bytes waiting to be used.
# TYPE go_memstats_heap_idle_bytes gauge
go_memstats_heap_idle_bytes 6.0178432e+07
# HELP go_memstats_heap_inuse_bytes Number of heap bytes that are in use.
# TYPE go_memstats_heap_inuse_bytes gauge
go_memstats_heap_inuse_bytes 5.259264e+06
# HELP go_memstats_heap_objects Number of allocated objects.
# TYPE go_memstats_heap_objects gauge
go_memstats_heap_objects 34961
# HELP go_memstats_heap_released_bytes Number of heap bytes released to OS.
# TYPE go_memstats_heap_released_bytes gauge
go_memstats_heap_released_bytes 0
# HELP go_memstats_heap_sys_bytes Number of heap bytes obtained from system.
# TYPE go_memstats_heap_sys_bytes gauge
go_memstats_heap_sys_bytes 6.5437696e+07
# HELP go_memstats_last_gc_time_seconds Number of seconds since 1970 of last garbage collection.
# TYPE go_memstats_last_gc_time_seconds gauge
go_memstats_last_gc_time_seconds 1.5860258690406542e+09
# HELP go_memstats_lookups_total Total number of pointer lookups.
# TYPE go_memstats_lookups_total counter
go_memstats_lookups_total 0
# HELP go_memstats_mallocs_total Total number of mallocs.
# TYPE go_memstats_mallocs_total counter
go_memstats_mallocs_total 1.969031335e+10
# HELP go_memstats_mcache_inuse_bytes Number of bytes in use by mcache structures.
# TYPE go_memstats_mcache_inuse_bytes gauge
go_memstats_mcache_inuse_bytes 13824
# HELP go_memstats_mcache_sys_bytes Number of bytes used for mcache structures obtained from system.
# TYPE go_memstats_mcache_sys_bytes gauge
go_memstats_mcache_sys_bytes 16384
# HELP go_memstats_mspan_inuse_bytes Number of bytes in use by mspan structures.
# TYPE go_memstats_mspan_inuse_bytes gauge
go_memstats_mspan_inuse_bytes 96672
# HELP go_memstats_mspan_sys_bytes Number of bytes used for mspan structures obtained from system.
# TYPE go_memstats_mspan_sys_bytes gauge
go_memstats_mspan_sys_bytes 229376
# HELP go_memstats_next_gc_bytes Number of heap bytes when next garbage collection will take place.
# TYPE go_memstats_next_gc_bytes gauge
go_memstats_next_gc_bytes 4.467872e+06
# HELP go_memstats_other_sys_bytes Number of bytes used for other system allocations.
# TYPE go_memstats_other_sys_bytes gauge
go_memstats_other_sys_bytes 1.622044e+06
# HELP go_memstats_stack_inuse_bytes Number of bytes in use by the stack allocator.
# TYPE go_memstats_stack_inuse_bytes gauge
go_memstats_stack_inuse_bytes 1.671168e+06
# HELP go_memstats_stack_sys_bytes Number of bytes obtained from system for stack allocator.
# TYPE go_memstats_stack_sys_bytes gauge
go_memstats_stack_sys_bytes 1.671168e+06
# HELP go_memstats_sys_bytes Number of bytes obtained from system.
# TYPE go_memstats_sys_bytes gauge
go_memstats_sys_bytes 7.4119416e+07
# HELP go_threads Number of OS threads created.
# TYPE go_threads gauge
go_threads 29
# HELP node_arp_entries ARP entries by device
# TYPE node_arp_entries gauge
node_arp_entries{device="eth0"} 1
node_arp_entries{device="eth1"} 1
# HELP node_boot_time_seconds Node boot time, in unixtime.
# TYPE node_boot_time_seconds gauge
node_boot_time_seconds 1.585553542e+09
# HELP node_buddyinfo_blocks Count of free blocks according to size.
# TYPE node_buddyinfo_blocks gauge
node_buddyinfo_blocks{node="0",size="0",zone="DMA"} 0
node_buddyinfo_blocks{node="0",size="0",zone="DMA32"} 909
node_buddyinfo_blocks{node="0",size="0",zone="Normal"} 28514
node_buddyinfo_blocks{node="0",size="1",zone="DMA"} 0
node_buddyinfo_blocks{node="0",size="1",zone="DMA32"} 882
node_buddyinfo_blocks{node="0",size="1",zone="Normal"} 5793
node_buddyinfo_blocks{node="0",size="10",zone="DMA"} 3
node_buddyinfo_blocks{node="0",size="10",zone="DMA32"} 201
node_buddyinfo_blocks{node="0",size="10",zone="Normal"} 0
node_buddyinfo_blocks{node="0",size="2",zone="DMA"} 0
node_buddyinfo_blocks{node="0",size="2",zone="DMA32"} 839
node_buddyinfo_blocks{node="0",size="2",zone="Normal"} 4811
node_buddyinfo_blocks{node="0",size="3",zone="DMA"} 1
node_buddyinfo_blocks{node="0",size="3",zone="DMA32"} 811
node_buddyinfo_blocks{node="0",size="3",zone="Normal"} 919
node_buddyinfo_blocks{node="0",size="4",zone="DMA"} 1
node_buddyinfo_blocks{node="0",size="4",zone="DMA32"} 767
node_buddyinfo_blocks{node="0",size="4",zone="Normal"} 496
node_buddyinfo_blocks{node="0",size="5",zone="DMA"} 1
node_buddyinfo_blocks{node="0",size="5",zone="DMA32"} 698
node_buddyinfo_blocks{node="0",size="5",zone="Normal"} 323
node_buddyinfo_blocks{node="0",size="6",zone="DMA"} 1
node_buddyinfo_blocks{node="0",size="6",zone="DMA32"} 462
node_buddyinfo_blocks{node="0",size="6",zone="Normal"} 507
node_buddyinfo_blocks{node="0",size="7",zone="DMA"} 0
node_buddyinfo_blocks{node="0",size="7",zone="DMA32"} 431
node_buddyinfo_blocks{node="0",size="7",zone="Normal"} 2010
node_buddyinfo_blocks{node="0",size="8",zone="DMA"} 1
node_buddyinfo_blocks{node="0",size="8",zone="DMA32"} 310
node_buddyinfo_blocks{node="0",size="8",zone="Normal"} 539
node_buddyinfo_blocks{node="0",size="9",zone="DMA"} 1
node_buddyinfo_blocks{node="0",size="9",zone="DMA32"} 141
node_buddyinfo_blocks{node="0",size="9",zone="Normal"} 29
# HELP node_context_switches_total Total number of context switches.
# TYPE node_context_switches_total counter
node_context_switches_total 9.800025068e+09
# HELP node_cpu_guest_seconds_total Seconds the cpus spent in guests (VMs) for each mode.
# TYPE node_cpu_guest_seconds_total counter
node_cpu_guest_seconds_total{cpu="0",mode="nice"} 0
node_cpu_guest_seconds_total{cpu="0",mode="user"} 0
node_cpu_guest_seconds_total{cpu="1",mode="nice"} 0
node_cpu_guest_seconds_total{cpu="1",mode="user"} 0
node_cpu_guest_seconds_total{cpu="2",mode="nice"} 0
node_cpu_guest_seconds_total{cpu="2",mode="user"} 0
node_cpu_guest_seconds_total{cpu="3",mode="nice"} 0
node_cpu_guest_seconds_total{cpu="3",mode="user"} 0
node_cpu_guest_seconds_total{cpu="4",mode="nice"} 0
node_cpu_guest_seconds_total{cpu="4",mode="user"} 0
node_cpu_guest_seconds_total{cpu="5",mode="nice"} 0
node_cpu_guest_seconds_total{cpu="5",mode="user"} 0
node_cpu_guest_seconds_total{cpu="6",mode="nice"} 0
node_cpu_guest_seconds_total{cpu="6",mode="user"} 0
node_cpu_guest_seconds_total{cpu="7",mode="nice"} 0
node_cpu_guest_seconds_total{cpu="7",mode="user"} 0
# HELP node_cpu_seconds_total Seconds the cpus spent in each mode.
# TYPE node_cpu_seconds_total counter
node_cpu_seconds_total{cpu="0",mode="idle"} 183967.47
node_cpu_seconds_total{cpu="0",mode="iowait"} 326.04
node_cpu_seconds_total{cpu="0",mode="irq"} 0
node_cpu_seconds_total{cpu="0",mode="nice"} 15.19
node_cpu_seconds_total{cpu="0",mode="softirq"} 71125.65
node_cpu_seconds_total{cpu="0",mode="steal"} 0
node_cpu_seconds_total{cpu="0",mode="system"} 117856.35
node_cpu_seconds_total{cpu="0",mode="user"} 99035.68
node_cpu_seconds_total{cpu="1",mode="idle"} 109905.1
node_cpu_seconds_total{cpu="1",mode="iowait"} 311.87
node_cpu_seconds_total{cpu="1",mode="irq"} 0
node_cpu_seconds_total{cpu="1",mode="nice"} 3.87
node_cpu_seconds_total{cpu="1",mode="softirq"} 73402.88
node_cpu_seconds_total{cpu="1",mode="steal"} 0
node_cpu_seconds_total{cpu="1",mode="system"} 153710.67
node_cpu_seconds_total{cpu="1",mode="user"} 134989.36
node_cpu_seconds_total{cpu="2",mode="idle"} 129971.94
node_cpu_seconds_total{cpu="2",mode="iowait"} 261.27
node_cpu_seconds_total{cpu="2",mode="irq"} 0
node_cpu_seconds_total{cpu="2",mode="nice"} 2.99
node_cpu_seconds_total{cpu="2",mode="softirq"} 73332.61
node_cpu_seconds_total{cpu="2",mode="steal"} 0
node_cpu_seconds_total{cpu="2",mode="system"} 145822.99
node_cpu_seconds_total{cpu="2",mode="user"} 122930.98
node_cpu_seconds_total{cpu="3",mode="idle"} 123175.48
node_cpu_seconds_total{cpu="3",mode="iowait"} 213.41
node_cpu_seconds_total{cpu="3",mode="irq"} 0
node_cpu_seconds_total{cpu="3",mode="nice"} 2.79
node_cpu_seconds_total{cpu="3",mode="softirq"} 72574.65
node_disk_read_time_seconds_total{device="nbd7"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-journald.socket",state="deactivating"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-journald.socket",state="failed"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-journald.socket",state="inactive"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-logind.service",state="activating"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-logind.service",state="active"} 1
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-logind.service",state="deactivating"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-logind.service",state="failed"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-logind.service",state="inactive"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-machine-id-commit.service",state="activating"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-machine-id-commit.service",state="active"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-machine-id-commit.service",state="deactivating"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-machine-id-commit.service",state="failed"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-machine-id-commit.service",state="inactive"} 1
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-modules-load.service",state="activating"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-modules-load.service",state="active"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-modules-load.service",state="deactivating"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-modules-load.service",state="failed"} 1
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-modules-load.service",state="inactive"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-networkd-wait-online.service",state="activating"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-networkd-wait-online.service",state="active"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-networkd-wait-online.service",state="deactivating"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-networkd-wait-online.service",state="failed"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-networkd-wait-online.service",state="inactive"} 1
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-networkd.service",state="activating"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-networkd.service",state="active"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-networkd.service",state="deactivating"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-networkd.service",state="failed"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-networkd.service",state="inactive"} 1
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-quotacheck.service",state="activating"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-quotacheck.service",state="active"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-quotacheck.service",state="deactivating"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-quotacheck.service",state="failed"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-quotacheck.service",state="inactive"} 1
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-random-seed.service",state="activating"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-random-seed.service",state="active"} 1
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-random-seed.service",state="deactivating"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-random-seed.service",state="failed"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-random-seed.service",state="inactive"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-remount-fs.service",state="activating"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-remount-fs.service",state="active"} 1
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-remount-fs.service",state="deactivating"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-remount-fs.service",state="failed"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-remount-fs.service",state="inactive"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-resolved.service",state="activating"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-resolved.service",state="active"} 1
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-resolved.service",state="deactivating"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-resolved.service",state="failed"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-resolved.service",state="inactive"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-sysctl.service",state="activating"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-sysctl.service",state="active"} 1
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-sysctl.service",state="deactivating"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-sysctl.service",state="failed"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-sysctl.service",state="inactive"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-timesyncd.service",state="activating"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-timesyncd.service",state="active"} 1
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-timesyncd.service",state="deactivating"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-timesyncd.service",state="failed"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-timesyncd.service",state="inactive"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service",state="activating"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service",state="active"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service",state="deactivating"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service",state="failed"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service",state="inactive"} 1
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-tmpfiles-clean.timer",state="activating"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-tmpfiles-clean.timer",state="active"} 1
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-tmpfiles-clean.timer",state="deactivating"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-tmpfiles-clean.timer",state="failed"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-tmpfiles-clean.timer",state="inactive"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service",state="activating"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service",state="active"} 1
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service",state="deactivating"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service",state="failed"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service",state="inactive"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service",state="activating"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service",state="active"} 1
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service",state="deactivating"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service",state="failed"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service",state="inactive"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-udev-trigger.service",state="activating"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-udev-trigger.service",state="active"} 1
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-udev-trigger.service",state="deactivating"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-udev-trigger.service",state="failed"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-udev-trigger.service",state="inactive"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-udevd-control.socket",state="activating"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-udevd-control.socket",state="active"} 1
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-udevd-control.socket",state="deactivating"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-udevd-control.socket",state="failed"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-udevd-control.socket",state="inactive"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-udevd-kernel.socket",state="activating"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-udevd-kernel.socket",state="active"} 1
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-udevd-kernel.socket",state="deactivating"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-udevd-kernel.socket",state="failed"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-udevd-kernel.socket",state="inactive"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-udevd.service",state="activating"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-udevd.service",state="active"} 1
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-udevd.service",state="deactivating"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-udevd.service",state="failed"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-udevd.service",state="inactive"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service",state="activating"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service",state="active"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service",state="deactivating"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service",state="failed"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service",state="inactive"} 1
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-update-utmp.service",state="activating"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-update-utmp.service",state="active"} 1
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-update-utmp.service",state="deactivating"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-update-utmp.service",state="failed"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-update-utmp.service",state="inactive"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-user-sessions.service",state="activating"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-user-sessions.service",state="active"} 1
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-user-sessions.service",state="deactivating"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-user-sessions.service",state="failed"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="systemd-user-sessions.service",state="inactive"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="thermald.service",state="activating"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="thermald.service",state="active"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="thermald.service",state="deactivating"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="thermald.service",state="failed"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="thermald.service",state="inactive"} 1
node_systemd_unit_state{name="time-sync.target",state="activating"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="time-sync.target",state="active"} 1
node_systemd_unit_state{name="time-sync.target",state="deactivating"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="time-sync.target",state="failed"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="time-sync.target",state="inactive"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="timers.target",state="activating"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="timers.target",state="active"} 1
node_systemd_unit_state{name="timers.target",state="deactivating"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="timers.target",state="failed"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="timers.target",state="inactive"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="udicorn-api-slave.service",state="activating"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="udicorn-api-slave.service",state="active"} 1
node_systemd_unit_state{name="udicorn-api-slave.service",state="deactivating"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="udicorn-api-slave.service",state="failed"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="udicorn-api-slave.service",state="inactive"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="ufw.service",state="activating"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="ufw.service",state="active"} 1
node_systemd_unit_state{name="ufw.service",state="deactivating"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="ufw.service",state="failed"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="ufw.service",state="inactive"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="umount.target",state="activating"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="umount.target",state="active"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="umount.target",state="deactivating"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="umount.target",state="failed"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="umount.target",state="inactive"} 1
node_systemd_unit_state{name="ureadahead-stop.service",state="activating"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="ureadahead-stop.service",state="active"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="ureadahead-stop.service",state="deactivating"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="ureadahead-stop.service",state="failed"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="ureadahead-stop.service",state="inactive"} 1
node_systemd_unit_state{name="ureadahead-stop.timer",state="activating"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="ureadahead-stop.timer",state="active"} 1
node_systemd_unit_state{name="ureadahead-stop.timer",state="deactivating"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="ureadahead-stop.timer",state="failed"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="ureadahead-stop.timer",state="inactive"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="ureadahead.service",state="activating"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="ureadahead.service",state="active"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="ureadahead.service",state="deactivating"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="ureadahead.service",state="failed"} 1
node_systemd_unit_state{name="ureadahead.service",state="inactive"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="user.slice",state="activating"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="user.slice",state="active"} 1
node_systemd_unit_state{name="user.slice",state="deactivating"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="user.slice",state="failed"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="user.slice",state="inactive"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="uuidd.service",state="activating"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="uuidd.service",state="active"} 1
node_systemd_unit_state{name="uuidd.service",state="deactivating"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="uuidd.service",state="failed"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="uuidd.service",state="inactive"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="uuidd.socket",state="activating"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="uuidd.socket",state="active"} 1
node_systemd_unit_state{name="uuidd.socket",state="deactivating"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="uuidd.socket",state="failed"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="uuidd.socket",state="inactive"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="var-lib-lxcfs.mount",state="activating"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="var-lib-lxcfs.mount",state="active"} 1
node_systemd_unit_state{name="var-lib-lxcfs.mount",state="deactivating"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="var-lib-lxcfs.mount",state="failed"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="var-lib-lxcfs.mount",state="inactive"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="vgauth.service",state="activating"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="vgauth.service",state="active"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="vgauth.service",state="deactivating"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="vgauth.service",state="failed"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="vgauth.service",state="inactive"} 1
# HELP node_systemd_units Summary of systemd unit states
# TYPE node_systemd_units gauge
node_systemd_units{state="activating"} 0
node_systemd_units{state="active"} 656
node_systemd_units{state="deactivating"} 0
node_systemd_units{state="failed"} 5
node_systemd_units{state="inactive"} 81
# HELP node_textfile_scrape_error 1 if there was an error opening or reading a file, 0 otherwise
# TYPE node_textfile_scrape_error gauge
node_textfile_scrape_error 0
# HELP node_time_seconds System time in seconds since epoch (1970).
# TYPE node_time_seconds gauge
node_time_seconds 1.5860258691063704e+09
# HELP node_timex_estimated_error_seconds Estimated error in seconds.
# TYPE node_timex_estimated_error_seconds gauge
node_timex_estimated_error_seconds 0
# HELP node_timex_frequency_adjustment_ratio Local clock frequency adjustment.
# TYPE node_timex_frequency_adjustment_ratio gauge
node_timex_frequency_adjustment_ratio 0.9999808583526612
# HELP node_timex_loop_time_constant Phase-locked loop time constant.
# TYPE node_timex_loop_time_constant gauge
node_timex_loop_time_constant 7
# HELP node_timex_maxerror_seconds Maximum error in seconds.
# TYPE node_timex_maxerror_seconds gauge
node_timex_maxerror_seconds 0.6035
# HELP node_timex_offset_seconds Time offset in between local system and reference clock.
# TYPE node_timex_offset_seconds gauge
node_timex_offset_seconds -7.075e-05
# HELP node_timex_pps_calibration_total Pulse per second count of calibration intervals.
# TYPE node_timex_pps_calibration_total counter
node_timex_pps_calibration_total 0
# HELP node_timex_pps_error_total Pulse per second count of calibration errors.
# TYPE node_timex_pps_error_total counter
node_timex_pps_error_total 0
# HELP node_timex_pps_frequency_hertz Pulse per second frequency.
# TYPE node_timex_pps_frequency_hertz gauge
node_timex_pps_frequency_hertz 0
# HELP node_timex_pps_jitter_seconds Pulse per second jitter.
# TYPE node_timex_pps_jitter_seconds gauge
node_timex_pps_jitter_seconds 0
# HELP node_timex_pps_jitter_total Pulse per second count of jitter limit exceeded events.
# TYPE node_timex_pps_jitter_total counter
node_timex_pps_jitter_total 0
# HELP node_timex_pps_shift_seconds Pulse per second interval duration.
# TYPE node_timex_pps_shift_seconds gauge
node_timex_pps_shift_seconds 0
# HELP node_timex_pps_stability_exceeded_total Pulse per second count of stability limit exceeded events.
# TYPE node_timex_pps_stability_exceeded_total counter
node_timex_pps_stability_exceeded_total 0
# HELP node_timex_pps_stability_hertz Pulse per second stability, average of recent frequency changes.
# TYPE node_timex_pps_stability_hertz gauge
node_timex_pps_stability_hertz 0
# HELP node_timex_status Value of the status array bits.
# TYPE node_timex_status gauge
node_timex_status 8193
# HELP node_timex_sync_status Is clock synchronized to a reliable server (1 = yes, 0 = no).
# TYPE node_timex_sync_status gauge
node_timex_sync_status 1
# HELP node_timex_tai_offset_seconds International Atomic Time (TAI) offset.
# TYPE node_timex_tai_offset_seconds gauge
node_timex_tai_offset_seconds 0
# HELP node_timex_tick_seconds Seconds between clock ticks.
# TYPE node_timex_tick_seconds gauge
node_timex_tick_seconds 0.01
promhttp_metric_handler_requests_total{code="500"} 0
promhttp_metric_handler_requests_total{code="503"} 0
```

Is this useful?

Comment: That is a node_exporter result metrics of the system, used by Prometheus for example.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with IS